# Can I include field names as first row when saving query as file in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

When running queries in MySQL, I use the command `SELECT [fieldnames] from [tablenames] INTO OUTFILE ['filename.txt`] a lot when saving my query as a file, so that I can open it in excel later on.

Is it possible to include the fieldnames as a first column in the output file?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you save the file? From Phpmyadmin, from MySQL Workbench, or from where?

Comment: no I just use MySQL at the command line in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned using the command-line in your comment, the easiest thing for you to do is just `UNION` your query with the headers - this way it will be a part of the file.

For example, if your table has the following fieldnames: `first_name`, `last_name`, `age`, your `SELECT` query will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Age' UNION 
     SELECT first_name, last_name, age FROM [tablenames]) 
INTO [outfile]
```

However, the **easiest** way is to just run the query in MySQL Workbench, and choose "Save with column names" when saving the results.

Comment: Workbench.. hmm.. to that matter: I didn't install it on first occasion, could I run into issues in order to still work from the command line after installing the Workbench? (setting up MySQL wasn't that straightforward and wouldn't want to have to go through that again.

Comment: @oaklander114 MySQL Workbench is just a GUI client for MySQL; its just a separate program that connects to it and gives you a nice user-friendly interface to run your queries and look at the results without having to use the command-line.

Comment: Thanks Ruslan. If I run a query with more than 1000 rows, only 1000 rows are shown in the output file when doing 'export'. Could you possibly tell me how to export all the rows in the query?